# Mongodb group by dayOfYear, but return formatted date

Tags: mongodb

I have an aggregation where I'm trying to count the total number of documents by day..

```
  {
    "$group" : 
      { 
        _id: { $dayOfYear: "$date" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }

  },
```

This works.  However, I don't want to only display the day of the week, I want to display a more formatted date, such as `Thu Dec 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)` for each day, which will ultimately be used in charts.

Any idea how I can do this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `$push` operator in the `$group` stage, to collect all the days in an array, and in the application code format them to whatever format you wish to.

```
{
    "$group" : 
      { 
        _id: { $dayOfYear: "$date" },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        "days":{$push:"$date"}
      }      
}
```